# How to use Grafana with my private OAuth server?

Tags: grafana

According to the [Grafana documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/) it is possible to configure OAuth with google or github accounts. I have my own OAuth server, is it possible to use it? did someone ever try it?

If it is not possible what are the option to secure the Grafana frontend with OAuth? Perhaps a reverse proxy?

Comment: [Automatic Authentication using Grafana API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389522/automatic-authentication-using-grafana-api)

Answer (score 3):

Since Grafana 4 it is doable. You get one more OAuth option called **Generic OAuth**. See http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#auth-generic-oauth  . It works for example with CloudFoundry UAA.