# Automatic Authentication using Grafana API

Tags: api, authentication, get, grafana, grafana-api

In my web application, I want to provide the ability to pass authenticated users from my dashboard across to [Grafana](https://grafana.com/).

Once a user logged in my dashboard using credentials, a link to Grafana Dashboard will be displayed on my application. When user clicks that link, he/she will be redirected to Grafana page and automatically log in without displaying the Grafana login page. I don't want my users must encounter a second login screen, where they will be confused as to what username/password to enter.

I've followed [Automatic login to grafana from web application](https://community.grafana.com/t/automatic-login-to-grafana-from-web-application/16801), [Auto login to grafana dashboard](https://community.grafana.com/t/auto-login-to-grafana-dashboard/13485), [Auto login to grafana from Web application using credentials or token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230407/auto-login-to-grafana-from-web-application-using-credentials-or-token)
 and [Automatic login by token url](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3752), but no luck. I couldn't find appropriate & clean solution.

I'm using Grafana v6.2.5 installed on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

How can I implement it? Any help would be appreciated.

Server Details: Ubuntu Server 18.04, Apache 2.4.29

Comment: It looks like a task for SSO. Use OIDC everywhere and you problem solved.

Comment: How can I integrate it? My application is developed using PHP 7.0.

Comment: For someone who might be interested, here is a nice article on node.js implementation of reverse proxy to do this.
https://techitmore.com/javascript/reverse-proxy-server-in-node-js-for-authenticating-a-third-party-service-grafana/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I've found a workaround using Grafana's [Generic OAuth Authentication](https://grafana.com/docs/auth/generic-oauth/).

**Step 1:** Create files with the following code in it.

`GrafanaOAuth.php`:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class GrafanaOAuth
{
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new GrafanaOAuth instance.
     * @param array $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect to authentication URL.
     * @param string $state
     * @return void
     */
    public function auth(string $state): void
    {
        $state = urlencode($state);
        $url = "http://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth?state={$state}&code=cc536d98d27750394a87ab9d057016e636a8ac31";
        header("Location: {$url}");
    }

    /**
     * User access token.
     * @return void
     */
    public function token(): void
    {
        $token = [
            'access_token' => $this->user['access_token'],
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expiry_in' => '1566172800', // 20.08.2019
            'refresh_token' => $this->user['refresh_token']
        ];

        echo json_encode($token);
    }

    /**
     * User credentials.
     * @return void
     */
    public function user(): void
    {
        $user = [
            'username' => $this->user['username'],
            'email' => $this->user['email']
        ];

        echo json_encode($user);
    }
}
```

`oauth/auth.php`:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__ . '/../GrafanaOAuth.php';

/**
 * Fetch the details of Grafana user from your database.
 */
$user = [
    'username' => 'nbayramberdiyev',
    'email' => 'nbayramberdiyev@outlook.com',
    'dasboard_id' => 'oNNhAtdWz',
    'access_token' => md5(uniqid('nbayramberdiyev', true)),
    'refresh_token' => md5(uniqid('nbayramberdiyev', true))
];

(new GrafanaOAuth($user))->auth($_GET['state']);
```

`oauth/token.php`:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require __DIR__ . '/../GrafanaOAuth.php';

/**
 * Fetch the details of Grafana user from your database.
 */
$user = [
    'username' => 'nbayramberdiyev',
    'email' => 'nbayramberdiyev@outlook.com',
    'dasboard_id' => 'oNNhAtdWz',
    'access_token' => md5(uniqid('nbayramberdiyev', true)),
    'refresh_token' => md5(uniqid('nbayramberdiyev', true))
];

(new GrafanaOAuth($user))->token();
```

`oauth/user.php`:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require __DIR__ . '/../GrafanaOAuth.php';

/**
 * Fetch the details of Grafana user from your database.
 */
$user = [
    'username' => 'nbayramberdiyev',
    'email' => 'nbayramberdiyev@outlook.com',
    'dasboard_id' => 'oNNhAtdWz',
    'access_token' => md5(uniqid('nbayramberdiyev', true)),
    'refresh_token' => md5(uniqid('nbayramberdiyev', true))
];

(new GrafanaOAuth($user))->user();
```

`custom.js`:

```
$(function() {
    'use strict';

    if (location.pathname === '/login') {
        location.href = $('a.btn-service--oauth').attr('href');
    }
});
```

**Step 2:** Edit Grafana configuration file which is located at `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` on Ubuntu / Debian, `/usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` on MAC, `<GRAFANA_PROJECT_FOLDER>/conf/custom.ini` on Windows.

Uncomment these lines and enter your `client_id`, `client_secret`, `auth_url`, `token_url`, `api_url`:

```
#################################### Generic OAuth ##########################
[auth.generic_oauth]
;enabled = true
;name = OAuth
;allow_sign_up = false
;client_id = some_id
;client_secret = some_secret
;scopes = user:email,read:org
;auth_url =
;token_url =
;api_url =
```

Like so:

```
#################################### Generic OAuth ##########################
[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
name = OAuth
allow_sign_up = false
client_id = YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID
client_secret = YOUR_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
scopes = user:email,read:org
auth_url = http://foo.bar/oauth/auth.php
token_url = http://foo.bar/oauth/token.php
api_url = http://foo.bar/oauth/user.php
```

**Step 3:** Place `custom.js` in `/usr/share/grafana/public/build/index.html` file (Ubuntu / Debian) at the bottom of `<body>` tag.

**Step 4:** Restart Grafana server.

- `sudo service grafana-server restart` (Ubuntu / Debian)
- `brew services restart grafana` (MAC)

For the example and detailed explanation, have a look at my [Github repo](https://github.com/nbayramberdiyev/grafana-generic-oauth).