# auto login with Grafana

Tags: authentication, iframe, grafana

Grafana version and OS:
**Grafana 10.4.1 enterprise on windows 10**

I'm trying to run Grafana (app not only dashboards/snapshots) inside an iframe in my web app, and I want to avoid having the users need to log in to Grafana when they are logged in into my website.

currently I can "bypass" with anonymous login.

that's my custom.ini file:

```
[server]

protocol = http

http_addr = 127.0.0.1

http_port = 8080

domain = 127.0.0.1

enforce_domain = false

[security]

allow_embedding = true

[auth]

login_cookie_name = grafana_session

disable_login = false

login_maximum_inactive_lifetime_duration =

login_maximum_lifetime_duration =

token_rotation_interval_minutes = 10

disable_login_form = false

api_key_max_seconds_to_live = -1

[auth.anonymous]

enabled = true

org_name = Main Org.

org_role = Viewer

[auth.basic]

enabled = false

[auth.proxy]

enabled = true

header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER

header_property = username

auto_sign_up = true

sync_ttl = 60

whitelist =

headers =

 enable_login_token = false
```

I followed these instructions:

- https://community.grafana.com/t/automatic-login-to-grafana-from-web-application/16801
- https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-auto-login-from-angular-button-click/71813

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. Are you sure this is a programming-related question? It looks like you dumped a support ticket in here

Comment: Ticket? This is not a support forum. Please have a look at [ask]

Comment: call this platform any name you like, im just looking for help configuring auto login to grafana when its embeded inside an iframe

Comment: Your on the wrong platform then as it seems your question is not programming-related, as already pointed out.

Comment: how is it not programing related. im trying to embed an open course app inside my project, and i want to have a SSO mechaniism for a users that is already logged in into my site wouldnt need to log in into Grafana when it launches inside my site.

i used the template for creating a ticket in Grafana's forum isnt is easy to understand my issue?

Comment: The only thing you've dumped is a config file, furthermore there is no code/attempts inside your question (except for some threads which no one is going to dig through) and you didn't tag the question with any programming language (or framework, if you are using one). Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389522/automatic-authentication-using-grafana-api) can help you figure it out